# Python: Searchable dictionary within a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python, not used to handling this kind of stuff.

The code I've written:

```
search = str.lower(raw_input("What are you looking for?" + " " ))

knowledge = {"apple": 123, "test" : "cats"}

def return_the_input(search):
    if search in knowledge:
        print knowledge.get(search)
    else:
       print "No."
    return_the_input(search)
```

So what I'd like for it to do would be to ask you what you're looking for (apple), then apple would display something similar to a Ls command in unix. So it would look like this:

"What are you looking for?" --input apple. Apple would then print out other values, like

Butter
Sauce
Snacks

And would then ask "What next?" --input butter

And all of the information I have on apple butter would display.

So do I set this up in the code as

```
knowledge = {"apple":{"butter": "info on butter here", "sauce": "info on sauce here"}, "cats":{et cetera}}
```

And then act upon that somehow to get the formatting I want? I assume maybe with some kind of For loop, or just print statements?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea would work. But then what if an item belonged under two categories? A better solution would be to store all of the pieces of knowledge and then have a data structure mapping search words to knowledge.

```
knowledge = [
    [("apple", "butter"), "made from cooked down apple sauce"],
    [("peanut", "butter"), "made from crushed peanuts"],
]

def make_terms_from_knowledge(info):
    search_terms = {}

    for n, item in enumerate(info):
        for i in item[0]:
            search_terms.setdefault(i, []).append(n)

    return search_terms

terms = make_terms_from_knowledge(knowledge)
print terms["butter"]

for entry in terms["butter"]:
    print knowledge[entry][1]
```

You will need to regenerate terms whenever knowledge changes length. This is very simple but should get you thinking down other paths plus show some Python tips.